# How to store the value of a column from each row of a list into a collection using Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a single column table and each entry of the table is a text area. After user fills out the text area in multiple rows, I want to store the data of each text area in a collection on click of a button. How can I do this in Meteor? The HTML template looks like this:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#each items}}
                    <tr>
                        <td id="notes">
                            <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
                            </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}
                </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to utilize the [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) Method of JQuery.

Example:

```
Template.yourtemplate.events({
    'click .button': function(e) {
        $("textarea").each(function(i) {
            YourCollection.insert($(this).val())
        })
    }
})
```